# AUC_shuffled score: IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type

Tags: python

I need to calculate a type of AUC score using the code from an academic paper. But I keep getting the same error. According to the traceback, seems like it's because the indices was not an integer. So I added a `int()` function to it. But then the problem occurs because of the it was used as a map object.

```
def AUC_shuffled(saliency_map, fixation_map, other_map, n_rep=100, step_size=0.1):
    '''
    Parameters
    ----------
    saliency_map : real-valued matrix
    fixation_map : binary matrix
        Human fixation map.
    other_map : binary matrix, same shape as fixation_map
        A binary fixation map (like fixation_map) by taking the union of fixations from M other random images
        (Borji uses M=10).
    n_rep : int, optional
        Number of repeats for random sampling of non-fixated locations.
    step_size : int, optional
        Step size for sweeping through saliency map.
    Returns
    -------
    AUC : float, between [0,1]
    '''
    other_map = np.array(other_map, copy=False) > 0.5
    if other_map.shape != fixation_map.shape:
        raise ValueError('other_map.shape != fixation_map.shape')
    # For each fixation, sample n_rep values (from fixated locations on other_map) on the saliency map
    def sample_other(other, S, F, n_rep, n_fix):
        fixated = np.nonzero(other)[0]
        indexer = map(lambda x: random.permutation(x)[:n_fix], np.tile(range(len(fixated)), [n_rep, 1]))
        r = fixated[np.transpose(indexer)]
        S_rand = S[r] # Saliency map values at random locations (including fixated locations!? underestimated)
        return S_rand

    
    return AUC_Borji(saliency_map, fixation_map, n_rep, step_size, partial(sample_other, other_map.ravel()))
```

Full traceback is here:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-ffb2b08fa4b6> in <module>()
----> 1 AUC_shuffled(b, c, o)

2 frames
<ipython-input-106-305a871c6ad5> in AUC_shuffled(saliency_map, fixation_map, other_map, n_rep, step_size)
    258         S_rand = S[r] # Saliency map values at random locations (including fixated locations!? underestimated)
    259         return S_rand
--> 260     return AUC_Borji(saliency_map, fixation_map, n_rep, step_size, partial(sample_other, other_map.ravel()))
    261 
    262 

<ipython-input-106-305a871c6ad5> in AUC_Borji(saliency_map, fixation_map, n_rep, step_size, rand_sampler)
    205         S_rand = S[r] # Saliency map values at random locations (including fixated locations!? underestimated)
    206     else:
--> 207         S_rand = rand_sampler(S, F, n_rep, n_fix)
    208     # Calculate AUC per random split (set of random locations)
    209     auc = np.zeros(n_rep) * np.nan

<ipython-input-106-305a871c6ad5> in sample_other(other, S, F, n_rep, n_fix)
    255         fixated = np.nonzero(other)[0]
    256         indexer = map(lambda x: random.permutation(x)[:n_fix], np.tile(range(len(fixated)), [n_rep, 1]))
--> 257         r = fixated[np.transpose(indexer)]
    258         S_rand = S[r] # Saliency map values at random locations (including fixated locations!? underestimated)
    259         return S_rand

IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type
```

I tried adding `indexer = int(indexer)` in the `sample_other` function, but instead I got

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'map'
```

Anyone can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The int() function can only handle a single number at a time. You are trying to convert a "map" object into an int type.

The numpy transpose function returns a map object - when you are trying to access a value in "fixated"

```
    r = fixated[np.transpose(indexer)]
```

you should be using integer indices and not a map.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Itay Vegh to point out the issue. The problem I got was because that the original code was written in Python 2.x, while the environment I ran it was Python 3.x

In Python 3.x, one needs to wrap up a `list()` outside of a map object to get a list.

The solution is as below:

```
indexer = map(lambda x: random.permutation(x)[:n_fix], np.tile(range(len(fixated)), [n_rep, 1]))
indexer = list(indexer) # just add this line
```